# Highcharts: Sort column stack order to ascending

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Currently, the order of the column stack is random. What I want to achieve is to sort the stack with the biggest value at the bottom and lowest at the top.

I tried [`series.dataSorting`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataSorting.sortKey) to no avail.

Here is a jsfiddle as to what I have tried so far: https://jsfiddle.net/karmablackshaw/5waou19L/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of columns in a stack is not random, it depends on a series order. There is no way to achieve such sorting through the API, but you can modify the positions of columns after the chart is created. For example:

```
  chart: {
    ...,
    events: {
      render: function() {
        const series = this.series;
        const plotBottom = this.plotTop + this.plotHeight;

        series.forEach(s => {
          s.points.forEach(point => {
            let cumulativeY = 0;
            const stackedPoints = series.map(serie => serie.points[point.index]);
            stackedPoints.sort((p1, p2) => p2.y - p1.y);

            stackedPoints.forEach(stackedPoint => {
              cumulativeY += stackedPoint.shapeArgs.height;
              const plotY = plotBottom - cumulativeY;
              stackedPoint.tooltipPos[1] = plotY;

              stackedPoint.graphic.attr({
                y: plotY
              });
            });
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/br97gz54/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.reversedStacks

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

Comment: @ppotoczek, thank youu! Your solution is much more simple that what was answered in the forum: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=40664&p=181037#p181037.

Comment: But I wonder what's the purpose of `this.plotTop + this.plotHeight`. I changed it to just plotHeight because other columns are being hidden due to being small. And it fixed it.

Comment: Hi @Karma Blackshaw, I am glad that I could help. The `plotTop` property is 0 in your case because you don't have any elements like a title or subtitle. Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/understanding-highcharts

Comment: I see. Thank you @ppotaczek. I appreciate the sharing of resources as well 