# Highcharts sorted stacked columns : position of labels

Tags: sorting, highcharts, stacked-chart

I need to sort a categorized stacked columns in Highcharts (sorting categories by totals and in each column, sorting series to ascending/descending).

I found the topic [Highcharts: Sort column stack order to ascending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74052286/highcharts-sort-column-stack-order-to-ascending) that seems to be a great solution to achieve that.

The result is visible here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/0ye9objs/

The two things I would like to conclude are:

1/ place correctly the value labels (they don't follow the series sorting). I tried to change the datalabel y position with :
`stackedPoint.dataLabel.y = plotY;`
without success

2/ make functional the click on legend (when you clic on Jane for instance it does not result the expected behaviour). If it's not possible : just disable the click and let available the hover

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the example a bit. There is an additional `sortStacks` function, which is called on chart load. Moreover, data-labels positions are corrected by using `attr` method and hidden series are ignored in the `sortSeries` function.

```
function sortStacks(chart) {
  const series = chart.series;
  const newSeries = [];
  let sortedPoints;

  series.forEach(s => {
    sortedPoints = [...s.points].sort((p1, p2) => p2.total - p1.total);
    s.setData(sortedPoints.map(p => p.y), false);
  });

  chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(sortedPoints.map(p => p.category));
}

function sortSeries(chart) {
  const series = chart.series;
  const yStart = chart.plotHeight;

  series[0].points.forEach((point, index) => {
    const points = series.map(s => s.points[index]);
    points.sort((p1, p2) => p2.y - p1.y);
    let lastY = 0;

    points.forEach((p, i) => {
      if (!p.series || !p.series.visible) {
        return false;
      }

      const newY = lastY ?
        lastY - p.shapeArgs.height :
        yStart - p.shapeArgs.height;

      lastY = newY;

      p.graphic.attr({
        y: newY
      });

      p.dataLabel.attr({
        y: newY + p.shapeArgs.height / 2 - p.dataLabel.height / 2
      });
      p.tooltipPos[1] = newY;
    });
  });
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    ...,
    events: {
      load: function() {
        sortStacks(this);
      },
      render: function() {
        sortSeries(this);
      }
    }
  },
  ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8fp96u1r/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

Comment: Thanks very much for this function, it's exactly what I need. Now, as my users can choose dynamically the kind of render (columns/bars/stacked or not, is it possible to enhance the ```sortSeries()``` function to get the sorting working if the chart is inverted (for instance : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/y9z8mwro/) and if the chart is not stacked (inverted or not, for instance : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/d5q3pm07), in this case, each serie should be sorted asc/desc in each categorie. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @vegaelce, I've adapted the function for an inverted chart: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zgfod0j6/ and for a not stacked one: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mg7yeoc4/

Comment: Many thanks for this solution. Just a last request about the not stacked chart. When the chart is inverted, the Tooltips and the Datalabels are not correctly placed : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/70yvz4qu/ (I tried to enhance the function with a case chart.inverted for the tooltips and datalabels, like in the stacked chart function but unsuccessfully). Could you just help me on this last request please ?

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7f9xaz8t/ you can find an example with an inverted, not stacked column chart. When a chart is inverted, x and y coordinates are reversed. Useful thread: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=29814

Comment: This works like a charms (it is so useful maybe it should be included in API functions of Highcharts) ! Thanks very much @ppotaczek